# SAGA Ordered Weighted Averaging tool in QGIS Errors

Tags: qgis, raster, saga, weighted-overlay

I'm attempting to use the SAGA Ordered Weighted Averaging tool in QGIS (3.16) and am running into a few errors. Every time I've run the tool I've used the same number of inputs as weights in the table, but I still seem to be getting errors around that. Originally, I tried running the tool with eight input layers and received this error:

```
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\saga\SagaAlgorithm.py", line 280, in processAlgorithm
s = '{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(values[i], values[i + 1], values[i + 2])
IndexError: list index out of range

Execution failed after 0.04 seconds
```

More recently, I tried using some other test rasters as inputs and only three input layers, you can see from the inputs that I have three layers and three weights given:

> Input parameters:
> { 'GRIDS' : ['C:/Users/ktyle/Documents/Thesis/Denver/OWA_Rasters_QGIS1/food_test.tif','C:/Users/ktyle/Documents/Thesis/Denver/OWA_Rasters_QGIS1/retail_test.tif','C:/Users/ktyle/Documents/Thesis/Denver/OWA_Rasters_QGIS1/wellbng_test1.tif'], 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Users/ktyle/Documents/Thesis/Denver/OWA_Rasters_QGIS1/owa_test.sdat', 'WEIGHTS' : [0.10,0.10,0.80] }

This time the tool actually ran for more than a few seconds, but at the end I still got an error, which seemed to say that I only gave one weight.

```
Parameters


Grid system: 200; 760x 678y; 420596.428700x 4331253.154300y
Input Grids: 3 objects (foodtest, retailtest, wellbngtest1)
Weights: Weights (columns: 1, rows: 1)
Output Grid: Output Grid

Error : Wrong weights table. Check table dimensions

C:\WINDOWS\System32>exit
Execution completed in 15.93 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/ktyle/Documents/Thesis/Denver/OWA_Rasters_QGIS1/owa_test.sdat'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/ktyle/Documents/Thesis/Denver/OWA_Rasters_QGIS1/owa_test.sdat
```

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?